# How to make DIV automatically scroll fit to screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm have 2 DIVs (1 and 2) both are 100% width, 100% height and position:absolute, what i'm trying to achieve is when user viewing DIV 1 and scroll about 10% down, DIV 2 automatically scroll to fit the screen.

here is the example code https://jsfiddle.net/d6bpr5o2/

```
<div id="one" class="content">
when user scroll like 10% down. the screen automatically scroll to the next div.
</div>

<div id="two" class="content">
this is second screen
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.content{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
}

#one{
    background:blue;
}

#two{
    top:100%;
    background:rgba(255,255,0,1.00);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: Look at this, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32393734/imitate-parallax-effect

Comment: Filddle will be good to work on this.

Comment: image is really good. but where is your code?

Comment: Your image does not correspond to the situation you describe . The divs in your image seem to have a static or relative position, not position absolute (by the look of it).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d6bpr5o2/ ... here is the simple code

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my code can help you?
https://jsfiddle.net/moongod101/zbyy7mc5/

```
$(function(){
    $div1 = $('.div1')
  $div2 = $('.div2')
    $div2Pos = $('.div2').offset().top;
  $time = 0
    $(window).scroll(function(){

    $scrollPos = $(this).scrollTop();
    $to = $div2Pos = 100

    if($scrollPos >= $to){

      if($time == 0){
        //Not scroll before
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $div2.offset().top
            }, 2000);
        $time ++
      }

    }


  });

});
```

Comment: yeah...this is almost what i'm trying to achieve...but it cannot scroll back to Div 1

Comment: Oh,sorry my fault,i help you update the code,hope this time i can soft you problem

Answer (score 0):

sounds like a bad architecture problem, never seen a need like this...sounds like you need a slider.

with ***royal slider*** you can achieve this OOTB, just set the slider to go up and down and not to the sides and some css to make it 100% screen

Answer (score 0):

Using @Felix Fong HTML

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/amarsingh/d6bpr5o2/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').bind('mousewheel', function(e){
        //var scroll = amountscrolled();
        //console.log(scroll)
        if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta /120 > 0) {
        if( $(this).prev().length){
            $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).prev().offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
        }
        else{
        if( $(this).next().length){
            $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(this).next().offset().top
            }, 2000);
        }
        }
        });






});
```

You can scroll down and up .Only problem you need to rectify is dont allow user to scroll when `scrollTop` animation runs.

Answer (score 0):

I did some messing around and came up with this solution: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w9s4a5hL/2/). It seems to work great.

Do note that this code scrolls with increments of 100vh. This is based of the height when loading the page. This could be solved by changing the variable with a $(document).resize() function, but that is getting a bit offtopic for this question.

I left in the "console.log() functions", those are not necessary to use for the code to work (besides debugging). If you want more explanation on the how of this code leave a reply.

**html**

```
<div id="no1">1</div>
<div id="no2">2</div>
<div id="no3">3</div>
```

**css**

```
div{
  height:100vh;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
}
#no1{
  background-color: red;
}
#no2{
  background-color: green;
}
#no3{
  background-color: blue;
}
body{
  margin: 0px;
}
```

**jQuery/javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var currentDiv = 0;
  $(document).scroll(function(){ 
    var $docScrollTop = $(document).scrollTop();
    if($docScrollTop > (currentDiv+0.1)*$windowHeight && $docScrollTop < (currentDiv+0.5)*$windowHeight){
    $(document).scrollTop((currentDiv+1)*$windowHeight);
    currentDiv++;
    console.log("down", currentDiv);
    }
   else if($docScrollTop < (currentDiv-0.1)*$windowHeight && $docScrollTop > (currentDiv-0.5)*$windowHeight){
    $(document).scrollTop((currentDiv-1)*$windowHeight);
    currentDiv--;
    console.log("up", currentDiv);
    }
  });//end scroll

});//end ready
```